# 'DateField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'

Tags: python, django, backend

I've been researching everywhere for an answer for this, but I'm just trying to add a widget to my DateField created on my models.py, where you can see the actual calendar, as if you were doing it directly through html with an input type=date. Since I have a few date fields, this has become a problem because they all need to have the same format as the rest of the form and the widget. Feel like the question has been answered but none of the answers or things I've found have returned a correct answer.

```
models.py

class InfoPersonal(models.Model):

    Fecha = models.DateField()
    cargo_act = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Nombres_y_Apellidos_completos = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Lugar = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Fecha_de_Nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True)
    Discapacidad= models.BooleanField()
    grado = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Edad = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(18), MaxValueValidator(80)])
    Tipo_de_Sangre = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=sangre_choice)
    Estatura = models.FloatField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(3.0), MinValueValidator(0.5)])
    Direccion_Domicilio_actual = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Manzana = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Villa = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parroquia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Telefono_Domicilio = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Telefono_Celular = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Telefono_Familiar = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cedula = models.IntegerField()
    estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=list_estado_civil)

    #Conyuge
    Nombre_completo_del_conyuge= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Direccion_Domiciliaria=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Cedula_de_Identidad=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Fecha_de_NacimientoC=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    Direccion_Trabajo=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono_del_trabajo=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    #Hijos
    Nombres= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Lugar_y_Fecha_de_NacimientoH = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Esposo_con_Discapacidad = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    Hijos_con_Discapacidad= models.BooleanField(blank=True)

    #InfoFamiliares
    Apellidos_y_Nombres_1= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono_Familiar_1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    Fecha_Nacimiento_1 = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    Relacion_de_Parentesco_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    
    Apellidos_y_Nombres_2= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono_Familiar_2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    Fecha_Nacimiento_2 = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    Relacion_de_Parentesco_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    
    Apellidos_y_Nombres_3= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono_Familiar_3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    Fecha_Nacimiento_3 = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    Relacion_de_Parentesco_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    
    Apellidos_y_Nombres_4= models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Telefono_Familiar_4 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Fecha_Nacimiento_4 = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    Relacion_de_Parentesco_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    
    Trabajan_familiares = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    Trabajan_Amistades = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

    #estudiosRealizados
    Primaria=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Lugar_Primaria= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Curso_Primaria= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Año_Primaria=models.IntegerField()
    Titulo_Primaria=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Secunadaria=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Lugar_Secundaria=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Curso_Secundaria=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Año_Secundaria=models.IntegerField()
    Titulo_Secundaria=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Superior=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Lugar_Superior=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Curso_Superior=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Año_Superior=models.IntegerField()
    Titulo_Superior=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Otros=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Lugar_Otros=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Curso_Otros=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Año_Otros=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Titulo_Otros=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    idioma=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```
forms.py
class Form_InfoPersonal(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InfoPersonal
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'Nombres_y_Apellidos_completos': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75','required':True}),
            'cargo_act': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75','required':True}),
            'Lugar': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'Fecha': forms.DateField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type':'date'})),
            'grado': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75','required':False}),
            'Edad' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'Tipo_de_Sangre' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75','required':True}),
            'Estatura': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'Direccion_Domicilio_actual': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),  
            'Manzana':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'Villa': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'parroquia': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'Telefono_Domicilio' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75' }),
            'Telefono_Celular': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'Telefono_Familiar': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            'cedula': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg mt-3 ml-4 w-75', 'required':True}),
            

        }
```

```
views.py
def formu_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = Form_InfoPersonal(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Su formulario ha sido llenado y guardado correctamente')
            return render(request, '')
    else:
        form= Form_InfoPersonal()
        
    return render(request, 'users/formu.html', context={'form':form})
```

```
error message
Internal Server Error: /formu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Descargas\RP3 trabajo\RP3 trabajo\users\views.py", line 247, in formu_view
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 437, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 444, in _clean_fields
    value = bf.initial if field.disabled else bf.data
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 127, in data
    return self.form._widget_data_value(self.field.widget, self.html_name)
  File "C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 224, in _widget_data_value
    return widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, html_name)
AttributeError: 'DateField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Comment: On a side note, I recommend creating a separate model with `Apellidos_y_Nombres`, `Telefono_Familiar`, `Fecha_Nacimiento`, and `Relacion_de_Parentesco`. You will also need a `ForeignKey` to relate this to a `PersonalInfo` object. Doing this will give you a lot of flexibility because one `PersonalInfo` will not be limited to only 4 of these sets of fields. You will also be able to have 0 without using up disk space in your database.

Comment: Just edited for full error message, and ok thanks for the recommendation will create a separate model to optimize the code

Comment: Another note: in python we use `PascalCase` for class names and `snake_case` for field names. The general thing is to be consistent. I see you sometimes use capital letters and sometimes lowercase. I recommend being more consistent as it will make it easier to understand your code in the future.

Comment: I do know but I always keep forgetting to follow some good practices, returning back to the question is there a way to avoid this error and add a widget without posting this no atributte value_from_datadict

Comment: I am looking into it. I'll get back with you when I find something.

Comment: What is line 247 in view.py?

Comment: 247. if form.is_valid():

Comment: def formu_view(request) starts at 243 ends in 254

Comment: You need to specify `DateInput` as the widget, not `DateField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong class for the widget. Change

```
            'Fecha': forms.DateField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type':'date'})),
```

to

```
            'Fecha': forms.DateInput(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type':'date'})),
                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

`forms.DateField` is intended for declaring the field of a form. It doesn't have a method `value_from_datadict()` as required by validation. `forms.DateInput` is the widget used for a date input. It has the desired method.

Comment: This generates a new Error, as I think I've tried it before. 
  'Fecha': forms.DateInput(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type':'date'})),
TypeError: DateTimeBaseInput.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

Comment: @RMDG2001 right...look at how you do all your other inputs. None of them have `widget=...`.